# VMWare Snapshot Cleanup

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, snapshot

Running a Win7 VMware VM (Not ESXi) on WinXP. Now the C: driver is full and want to increase the size. I used the VMWare CLI vmware-vdiskmanager to increase the size. But it throwing an error message that, "some.vmx snapshot exist". In the VMWare Infrastructure Web Access page, I don't see any snapshots to delete.

Is it safe to delete the snapshot files manually?? Or Are the any CLI option to clean-up all dependent snapshots??

Comment: The first question I have is does your virtual machine have any snapshots you have created.  You should be aware if you created any at some point.

Comment: Unfortunately, the person used it, is not with us any more. No back ground info. That's why I am planning to do a clean-up.

Comment: I would backup the files and verify the virtual still boots into the same state.

Comment: Let me try in this way..